# function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) kivy timer

Tags: python, timer, kivy

I'm trying to have a user input a time, and when they start the timer, the time the user inserted will start to countdown from that inputted time.

However I get the error updatetimer() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

What is the best way to return the value from an input so that it can be used throughout the rest of the script.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

from functools import partial


check=0

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        TextInput:
            id: ti
        Button:
            text: 'do something!'
            on_press: root.updatetimer(ti.text)
        Button:
            id: btn_0
            text: "press me to start timer"
            on_press: root.val0()
        Label:
        text:'timer'
    Label:
            id: timer
            text:str(30)
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def updatetimer(self,timeup):
        return timeup


    def val0(self):
        global check
        if(check==0):
            check=check+1
            Clock.schedule_interval(partial(my_callback, self), 1)

test = MenuScreen()

def my_callback(screen, dt):
    t = test.updatetimer()
    t -= 1
    screen.ids.timer.text = str(t)

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: In your function `my_callback(screen, dt)` you have the following statement: `t = test.updatetimer()`. The object `test` is considered the first argument (`self`), but you still have `timeup`. So the error makes sense

Comment: what should t = test.updatetimer() be changed to so that t would equal the inputted time by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I would tidy up the code a bit and keep the method names a little more descriptive and inside the Class.

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        TextInput:
            id: ti
        Button:
            id: btn_0
            text: "press me to start timer"
            on_press: root.startTimer(int(ti.text))
        Label:
            id: output
            text: "Here"
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    time = 0

    def printTime(self, t):
        self.ids.output.text = str(t)

    def tick(self, *largs):
        self.time -= 1
        self.printTime(self.time)

    def startTimer(self, t):
        self.printTime(t)
        self.time = t
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.tick), 1)
```

Here we have 3 methods on the class, one to call at the start, one each iteration, and one printing helper function. Of course, this counter won't stop at 0, which is likely what you want, but I'll leave that part up to you.

Remember that methods in a Class will pass `self` in as their first argument. I'd look at what the Clock.schedule_interval method does if you want to eventually cancel it:

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.ClockBase.schedule_interval